# celery flower connection issue with --persistent True

Tags: django, celery, flower

I was running celery flower 1.0.0 as a systemd service with `--persistent=True`. And every restart used to fail with error `SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE` which was in-depth because of `db type could not be determined` error message.

Upon removing `--persisten=True` it used to work perfectly on every restart, but then I couldn't get my celery flower database be intact after each restart.

Here is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, that `SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE` was because of my mis-configuration of sentry + raven.

Second, the real error `db type could not be determined` was arising because the new restarted service wasn't able to connect with the database of older flower service. I couldn't find out why is that so, but a very helpful GitHub issue is [here](https://github.com/mher/flower/issues/827).

Finally, I tried specifying `--db` flag to specify my flower database location and name. This resolved the issue for me. Now the service was able to restart successful even with `--persistent=True`.

Later, I found out that the default database which flower was creating was owned by the primary user of the host. But upon specifying `--db` flag in the service file, the database was owned by celery user. This was the real solution for me.

Take Away: If you are running flower as a systemd service, then make sure the flower database file is owned by the celery user. Or even better is to always use `--db` flag to save you from this problem.